# Powershell select ID element and click from web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell

I am looking to open and click a button from a webpage in powershell.

The element I am selecting is:

```
<span class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" id="BtnExportCSV" unselectable="on">Export Dashboard as CSV File</span>
```

In the web console if I run the below code the button successfully clicks:

```
document.getElementById("BtnExportCSV").click();
```

The script I am running in **powershell** is below.

```
# open the specified web site and commit the key
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://wegpage.com/")
$ie.visible = $true
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}

$doc = $ie.document

# commit the button
$commit = $doc.getElementById("BtnExportCSV")
if ($commit) { $commit.click() }
```

The webpage loads successfully, however the button does not click. Instead an error is produced:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
$commit = $doc.getElementByID("BtnExportCSV")
```

How do I get around this error? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why powershell?...also check in your task manager for IE processes left open by the PS script

Comment: in my humble experience using Invoke-WebRequest is way cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase the "d" in `getElementByID("BtnExportCSV")`

`$commit = $doc.getElementById("BtnExportCSV")`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately no luck. I get the same error